# putting date range to pdf in shiny app

Tags: r, pdf, datatable, shiny, download

I have an app which looks like  below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbdeE.png)

I would like to download datatable to pdf with that time period. but when i do it only table exports. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTvHv.png)

here is ma ui.R code:

```
library(shiny)
  jscode <- "shinyjs.closeWindow = function() { window.close(); }"


 shinyUI(fluidPage(   




  tags$head(
tags$style(HTML("
                @import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton');

                h2 {
                font-family: 'Anton';
                font-weight: 600;
                line-height: 0.7;
                color: #483D8B;
                }

                "))
),


titlePanel("ZESTAWIENIE 1 v 2"),


sidebarLayout(

  sidebarPanel( tags$head(
    tags$style(type="text/css", ".well { width: 150px; }"),
  tags$style(type="text/css", ".col-sm-4 { width: 170px;}"),
# tags$style(type="text/css", "#close {font-size: 12px; background-color:  #e6e6e6; }") ,
 tags$style(type="text/css", "#get_data { font-size: 12px; background-color:  #e6e6e6;}") ,
  tags$style(type="text/css", "#last_month { font-size: 12px;background-color:  #e6e6e6; }") ,
  tags$style(type="text/css", ".control-label { line-height: 2 ; font-size: 12px;   }") ,
 tags$style(type="text/css", "#text { width: 390px ; font-size: 11px } "),
 tags$style(type="text/css", "#DataTables_Table_0 td[text*='SAL']{ background:#DCDCDC; }") 


     ),

           #  actionButton("close", "Zamknij raport" ,width = '100%' ),
             actionButton("get_data", "Generuj report" ,width =  '100%' ),
             actionButton("last_month", "Ostatni miesiÄ…c", width = '100%' ),
             dateInput('start_date', "Data poczÄ…tkowa", min = '2017-11-01', value= format(Sys.Date()-1, "%Y-%m-01")),
             dateInput('end_date', "Data koĹ„cowa", min = '2017-11-01' ,value=   format(Sys.Date()-1, "%Y-%m-%d"))







),


 mainPanel(tags$head(
  tags$style(type="text/css", ".col-sm-8 { width: 89%; }")
 ),


  div(
    verbatimTextOutput("text"), DT::dataTableOutput("results"), style = "font-size:80%" ),



tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel(
           HTML('<footer>
               <h6> kontakt: kk </h6>
                </footer>')

  ))





) 



)





 ))
```

where shloud I put  verbatimTextOutput("text") which is responsible for showing date range to have that date if pdf  after downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `caption`

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
      dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Date range:",
             start = "2001-01-01",
             end   = "2010-12-31"),
      DT::dataTableOutput('table')
) 

server <- function(input, output, session) {

   output$table <- renderDataTable(
      head(iris),
      caption = paste("Report Data:", input$daterange1[1], "to", input$daterange1[2] ),extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
  dom = 'Bfrtip',
  buttons = c('pdf')
))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```